# jQuery on click only works on dynamically generated content

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamic, static, click

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and have two scenarios where the same content can be loaded via an AJAX call. Since there are two scenarios, I am using class as the selector as opposed to ID since the ID will only work on the first instance.

Scenario one, in the menu, an href element with class="firstlink".

Scenario two, a customised autocomplete which outputs a link as the search term, again, this link has the class "firstlink". The autocomplete script is called in the  of the document.

The following works clicking on the menu item class "firstlink" on first and subsequent loads/clicks on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".firstlink").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"resources/pageone.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
        $(".content-area").html(result);
    }});
});
});
```

Because the autocomplete adds the second link with the class "firstlink" into the DOM, the above doesn't work for the dynamically generated link with this same class, so I must use 'on', which I am using like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".firstlink", function () {
        $.ajax({url:"resources/pageone.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
        $(".content-area").html(result);
    }});
});
});
```

This works on the dynamically generated element with class "firstlink" but it does not work on the menu item with class "firstlink" which is in the DOM.

I have also tried in the same document ready function:-

```
$('.firstlink').on("click" ,function() {
        $.ajax({url:"resources/pageone.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
        $(".content-area").html(result);
    }});
});
});
```

This works with the static (already existing in DOM) element with class "firstlink" but not with the dynamically created element of the same class name.

I am sure there must be a reason for this and that I do not require to define the same piece of code twice for the same function, as "$(".firstlink").click(function(){" and "$(document).on("click",".firstlink", function () {" produce the same outcome - the same AJAX content is loaded.

Sample HTML code:-

Static HTML:-

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="firstlink">click here first</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="secondlink">click here second</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thirdlink">click here third</li>
</ul>
```

The dynamically generated by autocomplete (jQuery) link is like this:-

```
<div class="search-output">
    <a href="#" class="firstlink">please click here</a>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Delegation depends on event bubbling. If you have an element containing the static `.firstlink` that has a `click` handler, and it uses `stopPropagation()`, that will stop it from bubbling out to `document`.

Comment: I am not using stopPropagation() anywhere to my knowledge.

Edited OP with sample HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be ok using the delegated event, i.e: `.on("click", ".firstlink", function...`, i.e., this should be the preferred approach:

```
$(document).on("click",".firstlink", function (e) {
    $.ajax({url:"resources/pageone.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
    $(".content-area").html(result);
    return false;
}});
```

Also, because you mentioned that you are using a anchor tags ("links") you probably don't want the default browser action to trigger for your links (they might be refreshing the page). Returning false from the event handler will prevent that (it is equivalent to calling e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation()).

Make sure that there are no other event handlers (before document or direct) that aren't calling stopPropagation (or returning false). That would prevent the event from reaching document.

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gW5sp/) that shows it working

Also, `.click(function...)` is the same as `.on("click", function()...` 
http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have used $(document).on("click",".firstlink", function () { and as stated in the OP, this seems to only work the dynamically generated link with the firstlink class, not the link which is static and still exists in the DOM with the same class name.

Comment: I also changed it to function (e) and added return false; and it's still not working for both links. The console outputs no warnings or errors, both elements definitely have the class "firstlink" before and after I click on them.

Comment: Do you have any handlers registered that might be running on click for those elements. If one of those handlers stops propagation (i.e. e.stopPropagation or returns false) the handler in the document will not run.

Comment: I guess I do, yes. I have this:-
`  $("#nav ul li a").click( 
   function () {
    //do some other non-related stuff here.
    return false;
});`
Can this be overcome?

Comment: @GrantG I don't know the specifics of your project, but if what you are trying to do is to just prevent the default browser action, you can do so by calling e.preventDefault() in `$("#nav ul li a").click( function (e) ...`. It won't stop propagation but it will prevent the default action for the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks Rui. The whole point of using "return false" on menu clicks was to stop the page reloading/jumping due to href="#" and also because the menu is an accordion style with parent/childs with only childs actually 'active' links doing something.

I replaced instances of return false with e.preventDefault() and now, using $(document).on("click",".firstlink", function () { both links work.

If you haven't already got Super Hero status, there's time yet, it'll surely come. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @GrantG, an upvote and setting the answer as the right one would help :)